Converting index matches Google Sheets formula to Apps script
I need to index matches based on 2 columns and set the Data!I1:I values into the Tab N column.
=arrayformula(iferror( vlookup( G1:G & H1:H,{Data!G1:G&Data!H1:H,Data!I1:I},2,false)))

Worksheet Demo
The formula is working, but I need it to be converted into a Google Apps script.
I have tried, but I am getting an error. searchRow is not a function.
const mainData = ss.getSheetByName("Data");
const tab = ss.getSheetByName("Tab");
const searchValues = mainSS.getRange("G1:H").getValues();
const targetMatch = tab.getRange("G1:H").getValues();                
const matching = searchValues.map(searchRow =>{
const matchRow = targetMatch.find(r => r[0] == searchRow([0]))
return matchRow ? [matchRow([2])] : [null];
})
targetMatch.getRange("N1:N").setValues(matching);


What is the question? What stops you from writing the function in Google Apps Script by yourself?

I understand what you want. Please remember that this is not a place to request others to do a job for you. Posts on this site should be questions and answers. A question should be about a practical, detailed problem unique to programming. Ref. [tour]. What is one of your practical, detailed issues unique to programming that stops you from getting what you are looking for? If you do not know where to start, start by reading https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets.

Question is updated now.

I think that =arrayformula(iferror(vlookup(G1:G & H1:H,Tab!G1:G&Tab!H1:H,Tab!I1:I},2,false))) is not correct. So, I'm worried that you miscopied your formula. Can you confirm it again?

Thank you for replying. About formula is currect, when you put your showing formula =arrayformula(iferror(vlookup(G1:G & H1:H,Tab!G1:G&Tab!H1:H,Tab!I1:I},2,false))) into a cell, what result did you obtain? I think that your formula has  only one }, and it is not correctly encloded. So, I'm worried that you might have miscopied it. I apologize for this situation.

Yes, you are correct. Its updated now.

Thank you for replying. From your updated question, I proposed an answer. Please confirm it. If I misunderstood your question, I apologize.

In your situation, how about the following modification?
Modification points:

In your script, at const matchRow = targetMatch.find(r => r[0] == searchRow([0])), searchRow([0]) should be searchRow[0]. This is the reason for your current issue of searchRow is not a function..
Also, at return matchRow ? [matchRow([2])] : [null];, matchRow([2]) should be matchRow[2]. But, targetMatch has 2 columns from const targetMatch = tab.getRange("G1:H").getValues();. So, in this case, undefined is returned.
I guess that in your situation when an object for searching values is created outside the loop, the process cost might be reduced.

When these points are reflected in the script, how about the following modification?
Modified script:
function myFunction() {
  const sheetName1 = "Tab";
  const sheetName2 = "Data";

  // Retrieve sheets.
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const [sheet1, sheet2] = [sheetName1, sheetName2].map(s => ss.getSheetByName(s));

  // Retrieve values from both sheets.
  const lastRow1 = sheet1.getLastRow();
  const values1 = sheet1.getRange("G1:H" + lastRow1).getValues();
  const values2 = sheet2.getRange("G1:I" + sheet2.getLastRow()).getValues();

  // Create an object for searching.
  const obj2 = new Map(values2.map(([g, h, i]) => [`${g}${h}`, i]));

  // Create the result array.
  const res = values1.map(([g, h]) => [obj2.get(`${g}${h}`) || null]);

  // Put the result array to column "O" of "Tab" sheet as a sample.
  sheet1.getRange(`O1:O${lastRow1}`).setValues(res);
}

When this script is run, the result values are put into column "O". Because your Spreadsheet has values in column "N". When you want to put the values to column "N", please modify sheet1.getRange(`O1:O${lastRow1}`).setValues(res); to sheet1.getRange(`N1:N${lastRow1}`).setValues(res);.
References:

map()
Map


Thanks, In the create the result array section, how can we declear not match instead of null? If i add "not match", the res return to empty rows too. I need response only if match both range otherwise return not match where g h col has value.

@Jebra About your new question In the create the result array section, how can we declear not match instead of null? If i add "not match", the res return to empty rows too. I need response only if match both range otherwise return not match where g h col has value., I would like to support you. But I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your new question. Can I ask you about the details of your new question?

I mean, i need a validation of null if the value is null, it will show as error text in the cells.

@Jebra Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my very very poor English skill again. I cannot still understand i need a validation of null if the value is null, it will show as error text in the cells.. Can you provide the sample input and output values you expect? By this, I would like to try to understand your new question.
